# Colour shapes based on value in array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to automate colouring shapes in excel dependent on values in a table. The approach I have taken is to read the table into an array, then I want to use this to determine how to colour the shapes. The problem I'm having is when I use the array to select a shape, it would appear that I get an array index number, not the actual value.

I would greatly appriciate a pointer in the right direction as I have spent a few hours trying to find a soulution without luck.

Table data:

```
Shape   Value
AB      900
DD      99
DG      647
EH      513
FK      191
G       446
HS      369
IV      259
KA      601
KW      351
KY      23
ML      509
PA      987
PH      167
TD      325
ZE      873
```

VBA Code:

```
Public i As Variant
Public j As Integer

Function mkArray()

    Dim areaArr As Variant
    areaArr = Range("I1:J16").Value

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    For i = 1 To UBound(areaArr, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(areaArr, 2)
            Debug.Print areaArr(i, j)
        Next j
            Call colourShapes
    Next i
End Function

Sub colourShapes()

    If j >= 500 Then
        Call formatGreen
    Else
        Call formatRed
    End If
End Sub

Sub formatGreen()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes(i).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 11
    End With
End Sub

Sub formatRed()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Shapes(i).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need globals for this.  A simpler version might be something like:

```
Function mkArray()

    Const COLR_GREEN As Long = 11
    Const COLR_RED As Long = 2

    Dim areaArr As Variant, i As Long
    areaArr = ActiveSheet.Range("I1:J16").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(areaArr, 1)

        Debug.Print areaArr(i, 1), areaArr(i, 2)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes(areaArr(i, 1)).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = _
                          IIf(areaArr(i, 2) > 500, COLR_GREEN, COLR_RED)

    Next i

End Function
```

If you really want to split into separate subs then you should use parameters in place of globals:

E.g.

```
Function mkArray()

    Dim areaArr As Variant, i As Long
    areaArr = ActiveSheet.Range("I1:J16").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(areaArr, 1)

        ColorShape Cstr(areaArr(i, 1)), areaArr(i, 2)

    Next i

End Function


Sub ColorShape(shpName as string, shpVal)
    Const COLR_GREEN As Long = 11
    Const COLR_RED As Long = 2

    Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes(shpName).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = _
                IIf(shpVal > 500, COLR_GREEN, COLR_RED)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was trying to acheive... and more simple than I realised.

Answer (score 1):

This will likely work:

```
Sub myColor()

Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim row As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set rng = Range("I2:J17")
i = 1

For Each row In rng.Rows

    myShapeName = row.Cells(1, 1).Value
    myShapeValue = row.Cells(1, 2).Value

    If myShapeValue >= 500 Then

        myFill = 11

    Else

        myFill = 2

    End If

    ActiveSheet.Shapes(i).Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = myFill

    i = i + 1


Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your response but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for as I don't need to format the cells the data is in (those cells won't be visable), the shapes correspond to areas (objects) on a map. It is these objects that I need to colour.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I understand better now.  I will post another answer then, I apologize for that.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This will apply a colour to shapes, however, not to the correct shapes. I notice it missed the entry for AB so I tried ammending `myShapeName` to `myShapeName = row.Cells(0, 1).Value` and `myShapeValue` to `myShapeValue = row.Cells(0, 2).Value`. It not captures AB but still not quite right... I have another go later.